# Rails Attribute Not Showing / Saving as Blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, attr-accessible, attr-accessor

The attribute, balanced_card_uri, is saving as blank and not showing on this raise:

https://img.skitch.com/20120916-fpmxabwg6m4ys3y84rkti615iq.jpg

Here's the code from customer.rb: https://gist.github.com/ee0b27bebe14d88417d9

After first having problems, I realized I misnamed the attributes in attr_accessble and attr_accessor. I renamed them correctly and the balanced_card_uri still shows blank...

Help!

Answer (score 1):

You raise an error all the time in `balanced_customer`. Why don't you add some conditionnal statements?

Example:

```
raise "Balanced Card: #{balanced_card_uri} Email: #{email}" if balanced_card_uri.blank? && email.blank?
```

Anyway, it's not the way to proceed, you should use validations. Example:

```
validates :balanced_card_uri, presence: true
```

Check [this page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#validation-helpers) for additional info.

---

Sidenote: why didn't you add `recurring_amount` and `recurring` to your `attr_accessible` ?

---

Side-sidenote:

Replace:

```
before_save :handle_recurring_donations, :if => :recurring
```

With:

```
before_save :handle_recurring_donations, :if => :recurring?
```

---

The problem seems to stem from your `find_or_initialize_by_repeat_donator`: you don't take any param into account there.

You should have a line like:

```
 customer.load(attrs)
```

With all the params you want to keep.

Comment: Yes, I know I'm raising that error all the time. I'm purposefully doing so in development to debug.

Comment: This still doesn't solve the problem that's happening in my screenshot.

Comment: I just updated the gist to include the create method of customer_controller and the full code in customer.rb

https://gist.github.com/ee0b27bebe14d88417d9

Comment: and what do you have in params?